# In android AppLock application for pinlock screen what should i use activity or dialog?

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I am making an android applock application which allow user the ability to lock specific applications.So basically my Question is for (Pinlock screen) that i use for pin or password before app start should be an activity or dialog? and when user enter correct password.How to resume that application again which user want to open after entering corect pin?

Comment: Well, to display the dialog you'd at least need an Activity. And since onResume (should) be called any time your Activity resumes focus, it makes it a great time to check whether a lock screen should be shown and handle accordingly. As for whether it should be a dialog or a fullscreen Activity you show them really depends on whether you want the information below the dialog visible before they've unlocked or not.

Comment: Every applock applications show pinlock screen on specific app without pausing that activity that is below the pinlock screen how they do it?

Comment: if i use activity as a pinlock screen and when i call it on any specific app open or start. it automatically pause that app which is below the pinlockscreen, so is there any solution of my problem?

Comment: Basically in my app a service is running.That continuously checking running process list. when any app which i want to secure is at 0 processses than i  show my pinlock screen.  ((appProcesses.get(0).processName.equals(etc app that i want to secure by pinLock) ))

Comment: Thanx Guardanis but need more help :)